# zstd block compression in MongoDB/Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, wiredtiger, zstd

I use docker-compose under Windows 10 like so:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${PWD}/mongod.conf
        target: /etc/mongod.conf
    entrypoint: ["mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--config", "/etc/mongod.conf"]
```

My mongod.conf:

```yaml
storage:
  wiredTiger:
    collectionConfig:
      blockCompressor: zstd
      configString: "allocation_size=64KB,internal_page_max=64KB,leaf_page_max=64KB"
```

Still I get the same disk size use when I `docker exec docker_mongo_1 df` both with and without zstd. With zstd:

```sh
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       65792556  49263808  13156972  79% /data/db
```

Without:

```sh
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       65792556  47991952  14428828  77% /data/db
```

(The slight variation is due to randomness of inserted data, but the number of documents and their sizes is within a few percent of each other.) I used mongodump from snappy and mongorestore into zstd to ensure most documents are untouched before running some tests.

Is a zstandard installation required on the Mongo docker image? Or am I lacking some mongodb/docker configuration? Or is it really not effective for my data? If so: why is that and can I make it effective? Or is the docker platform the problem? Or is it Docker on Windows?

**PS** The reason I'm not posting on a dba forum is that the question is multi-disciplinary.

Comment: To verify compression is used, inspect the relevant server parameters.

Comment: I verified compression was used by inspecting the relevant server parameters.

Comment: In that case your claimed "same disk size" output isn't actually the same.

Comment: In that case I reiterate my sentence about slight variation.

Comment: I'd recommend two things: 1. Try these steps without docker. 2. Ask this question here: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/

Comment: Is it overlay2 volume driver that you use in docker?

Comment: I don't think so, as I'm running on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Your method of measuring disk usage by mongodb is not a good one. `docker` doesn't emulate a virtual machine with its own virtual disks, so `df` actually shows disk usage statistics of the host machine (as a result your numbers include all disk activity happening outside docker). Better run `du -sh` on the directory where mongodb stores its data.